# Breaking Bootstrap Grid at Post Count with Tax Terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, count

I'm trying to get my custom tax term grid to break (insert a clearfix) after my 4th column. Below is my code. I've seen and done this before using a technique similar to what's demonstrated [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955818/wordpress-loop-posts-in-bootstrap-3-grid-layout). However, I'm not using a traditional loop so I'm really not sure how to go about implementing this. Look forward to your feedback.

Below is the code @Josh Mountain suggested. The break is not appearing at the correct place. I have also attached a screen shot of what I'm trying to accomplish as well as the current result. [image]

Code below updated 8-19-20 1:51 cst.

```
<div class="row">

    <?php

    $libargs=array(  
      'orderby'           => 'name', 
         'order'             => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'        => 0,  
        'exclude'           => array(16, 20, 22,25, 27, 28, 30, 4, 42, 7, 43 ), //* Enter ID's of parent categories to exclude from list
        'taxonomy'      => '100list',
        'parent'                   => '',
        );  

        $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

        $i = 0;

        foreach($libcats as $lc){

            $i++;

            if( $i % 4 == 0 ) {
             echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
            }

            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">';

            $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, '100list' );
        ?>


        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <br/><br/>   
                <h1><span class="label label-warning"><?php echo  $lc->count  ?></span></h1>
                <p> Symbols </p>

                <p> <a class="label label-default" href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"> View Group</a> </p> 

                <!-- basic text field display start -->
                <p>    <?php the_field('basictext', '100list_'.$lc->term_id); ?></p>
                <!-- basic text field display end -->

            </div>

            <!-- Get Image by Attachment ID Start-->
            <?php 

                $attachment_id = get_field('taximage', '100list_'.$lc->term_id);

                if ($attachment_id) {
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'industrygroup-img');

                    if ($image) {
                        ?>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                        <?php 
                    } 
                } 

            ?>
            <!-- Get Image by Attachment ID End-->

        </div>

    <small><p class="text-center"> <a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"> <?php echo $lc->name; ?></a> </p>  </small>

    <?php   echo '</div>'; }?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where you want your clearfix to come in, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <?php

    $libargs=array(  
      'orderby'           => 'name', 
         'order'             => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'        => 0,  
        'exclude'           => array(16, 20, 22,25, 27, 28, 30, 4), //* Enter ID's of parent categories to exclude from list
        'taxonomy'      => 'industrygroups',
        'parent'                   => '',
        );  

        $libcats=get_categories($libargs);  

        $i = 0;

        foreach($libcats as $lc){

            if( $i % 4 == 0 ) {
                /* INSERT CLEARFIX STUFF */
            }

            $i++;

            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 ">';

            $termlink = get_term_link( $lc->slug, 'industrygroups' );
        ?>


        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <br/><br/>   
                <h1><span class="label label-warning"><?php echo  $lc->count  ?></span></h1>
                <p> Symbols </p>

                <p> <a class="label label-default" href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"> View Group</a> </p> 

                <!-- basic text field display start -->
                <p>    <?php the_field('basictext', 'industrygroups_'.$lc->term_id); ?></p>
                <!-- basic text field display end -->

            </div>

            <!-- Get Image by Attachment ID Start-->
            <?php 

                $attachment_id = get_field('taximage', 'industrygroups_'.$lc->term_id);

                if ($attachment_id) {
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'industrygroup-img');

                    if ($image) {
                        ?>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                        <?php 
                    } 
                } 

            ?>
            <!-- Get Image by Attachment ID End-->

        </div>

    <small><p class="text-center"> <a href="<?php echo $termlink; ?>"> <?php echo $lc->name; ?></a> </p>  </small>

    <?php   echo '</div>'; }?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think we are on the right page. However, when I use that code, by grid breaks in an odd way. It doesn't insert the clearfix after the 4th grid item on every line - see first line. Can you look at this link? http://www.runningalpha.com/100indexlist/

Comment: @streetfire I just see a coming soon page. Maybe you could post what the markup is supposed to look like or where you want the break(s)?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my question above. Hopefully that helps. If not, I can remove the coming soon mask.

Comment: You appear to have a classic off-by-one error here. You initially set `$i=0`, then immediately inside your `foreach()` loop you're setting it to `1` (using `$i++`).  If you move the `$i++` line so that it's immediately *after* your `clearfix` stuff, does it work as desired?

Comment: @streetfire I have updated my answer to move the increment after the clearfix.